# How to use arguments with 'find -exec'?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-12.04, find

I'm trying to generate static html files for all php scripts inside dir:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec php {} > {}.html \;
```

But it just dumps all results to `{}.html`. How to do it properly? And how to remove '.php' from filenames?

Comment: Please do not cross post between different sites.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/513380/30957

Comment: The first part is answered here: [*Redirection or pipe inside `find -exec`*](https://superuser.com/q/1411712/432690).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [it was cross-posted to U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78316/108618) and answered there. Cross-posting is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310).

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
find . -name "*.php" | sed "s/\.php//" | xargs -i sh -c 'php {}.php > {}.html'
```